# Проверка существования изображения из javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть некоторая картинка по URL. Как можно из javascript определить существует ли она на самом деле? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если на своём сервере - сделать ajax запрос и проанализировать код ответа.

Иначе <img src="..." onload="{картинка_есть}" alt=""/>

Answer (score 0):

[onerror](http://wap.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp)

> Выполняет JavaScript, если происходит ошибка при загрузке изображения
>
> `object.onerror="SomeJavaScriptCode"`